# Finding GCD of two polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am finding the GCD ($x^{24}-1, x^{15}-1$) using Euclidean Algorithm. So far I have

EDIT:
$x^{24}-1=x^9(x^{15}-1)$ w remainder $x^9-1$, then $x^{15}=x^6(x^9-1)$ with the remainder $x^6-1$, then $x^9-1=x^3(x^6-1)$ with remainder $X^3-1$, then $x^6-1=x^3(x^3-1)$ with remainder $x^3-1$. Then obviously $x^3-1=1(x^3-1)$ hence our GCD is $x^3-1$.

Thanks everyone for dealing with my dummy moment!

Comment: How did you get $x^6-1 = x^2(x^3-1)$ with remainder $x^2-1$? It shouldn't be too hard to check your calculations and to find that this is incorrect. Otherwise, yes, you are doing this the right way; but then we have to wonder, if your computations were actually right, which they aren't, why you not know how to divide $x^3-1$ by $x^2-1$. Do you know how to divide one polynomial by another polynomial, or not?

Comment: I would like to delete this question. I just realized I'm a huge dummy.

Comment: $x^6-1=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)$ so the gcd is actually $x^3-1$

Comment: @KMath leave the question for a while, it might get a "showcase" answer - which you could make yourself if you like. If nothing in an hour or two then you could delete.

Comment: Interesting to note, $\gcd(x^m-1,x^n-1)=x^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^6-1 = x^3(x^3 -1 ) + x^3 -1$$
$$x^3-1 = 1(x^3-1) + 0$$
$$\gcd{(x^{24}-1, x^{15}-1)}=\gcd{(x^3-1,0)}$$

Therefore, $\gcd{(x^{24}-1, x^{15}-1)}=x^3-1$